# For in loop in recursive function not completing

Tags: javascript, recursion

I cannot get my for in loop to keep working after the first property in my object. This is a question from Eloquent JavaScript in Chapter 4:

> Write a function, deepEqual, that takes two values and returns true
>   only if they are the same value or are objects with the same
>   properties whose values are also equal when compared with a recursive
>   call to deepEqual.
>
> To find out whether to compare two things by identity (use the ===
>   operator for that) or by looking at their properties, you can use the
>   typeof operator. If it produces "object" for both values, you should
>   do a deep comparison. But you have to take one silly exception into
>   account: by a historical accident, typeof null also produces "object".

Here is my code:

```
function deepEqual(obj1, obj2) {
  if ((typeof obj1 === 'object' && obj1 != null) && (typeof obj2 === 'object' && obj2 != null)) {
    for (var property in obj1) {
      if (property in obj2) {
        return deepEqual(obj1[property], obj2[property])
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  } else if (obj1 !== obj2) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

var obj = {object: 3, here: 1};
var obj2 = {object: 3, here: 2};

console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj2));
```

The console returns true, when it should say false because the 'here' properties are not equal. When looking into the output, it's because the 'for in loop' in the function quits after the first property. Please help me as to why it's not continuing to loop.

Answer (score 0):

your for loop can't move beyond the first property because you return out of the function when you call deepEqual

```
 for (var property in obj1) {
      if (property in obj2) {
        // returning means no more looping....
        return deepEqual(obj1[property], obj2[property])
      }
```

you want to carry on looping if `deepEqual` returns that its equal, or return if its false.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Your answer makes sense, and I got it to work by replacing the return with : `if (!deepEqual(obj1[property], obj2[property]))
          return false;`.